# Primeng DataTable Global filter default value not filtering

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

In my application created the component using primeng dataTable, on that using the global filter. It's working as expected while manually type in the input. But the same not working when we provide the default value to the input.

```
<input #gb type="text" 
        placeholder="Global search.." class="changeListComponent_inputSearch"  [(ngModel)]="jiraRef">
```

while setting the value to the jiraRef not filtering the data, but if i do any keyboard action on the input it's working.

How can I trigger the keyboard action on the input code.

Comment: You want to call a function on input change?

Comment: I want to trigger the keypress event on the input while setting the value

Comment: Check my answer now.

Comment: Did you figure this out?